# Get "rounded numbers" by a round function

Tags: php

Is there a way in PHP to get what the `round` function has rounded.

I mean, let's assume I have

```
$totalRows = 54;
$v = round($totalRows, -1);

print $v // prints 50
```

This is fine but I was wondering if there were a way to get the number 4 which has been removed rounding `$totalRows`.
I'm aware that this might have little to do with the `round()` function but it is just an example of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: The operation you are looking for is called modulo. Try $totalRows % 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rounding to the nearest 10. You can use modulo 10 to get the remainder:

```
$totalRows = 54;
$remainder = $totalRows % 10;

print $remainder; //prints 4
```

Comment: @DonCallisto you have reason and it would be as obvious as simple but I was looking for something like Frank Egan suggested. I knew there were something like that but it wasn't there in my head :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

```
print $totalRows - $v;
```

As far as I know, there's not a function to retrieve it, but pure mathematical operation should be good enough.